# Derivative of $\sqrt[3]{x} e^x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$y=\sqrt[3]{x} e^x$$
I have no idea how to solved it.

Comment: Use the product rule.

Comment: I am new, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with writing $\sqrt[3]x=x^{\frac 13}$.  Then use the product rule.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\frac{d (uv)}{dx}=u \frac{dv}{dx}+v\frac{du}{dx}$$

and $$\frac{d (x^m)}{dx}= mx^{m-1}$$ as proved [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Power_Rule_for_Derivatives)

Comment: This rule does work if $m=-1$..

Comment: @CameronWilliams, thanks. Rectified